# T-SQL Parent/Child relationship in query, is there a better way than this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For this question, I don't really need the most efficient method as far as SQL Server perfection is concerned, but the easiest method for a beginner to handle a single level of parent/child relationships within a T-SQL query, without too much deviation from that SQL Server perfection.

For example:

```
EmployeeID | BossID | Sort
--------------------------
1          | NULL   | 1
2          | 1      | 1
3          | 1      | 2
4          | NULL   | 2
5          | 2      | 1
```

The records with NULL for BossID is the boss, whereas the others have a boss. Quite simple.

What I need is a T-SQL/SQL query so the results appear like so:

```
Boss
  Employee
  Employee
Boss
  Employee
```

As well as follow the sort order of the boss, and the sort order of the employee. So the Boss's are in the proper order, with the employees in their proper order beneath their boss.

I know how to do this, but what I'm looking for is critique on the method. I need the easiest method to explain to someone who's new in general. Looking at tons of examples I see lots of methods, from recursion to insanely complicated yet cool stuff from various sources.

Here's how I'm handling it now, which works:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    EmployeeID
   ,BossID
   ,Sort
   ,Sort AS Above
   ,NULL AS Below

FROM Employee
WHERE BossID IS NULL

UNION

SELECT 
   e.EmployeeID
  ,e.BossID
  ,e.Sort
  ,x.Sort AS Above
  ,e.Sort As Below

FROM Employee AS e
JOIN Employee x on e.BossID = e.EmployeeID
WHERE e.BossID is not null
) as Employees
order by Employees.Above, Employees.Below
```

So looking for critique. Is there anything wrong with this method that would be frowned upon by a SQL guru? Keep in mind I need it as easy as possible for a beginner to understand.

Comment: You should use UNION ALL for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Recursive Common Table Expressions. These kinds of hierarchical queries are the best solved with that.

Comment: Do you think considering it's only one level deep there's a simpler method than CTE?

Comment: You sent me on a rabbit trail... :) Still reviewing this and asking an additional question. Thank you for your fast response.

Comment: If you know that the recursion can only be one level deep, then a recursive CTE is overkill.

Comment: @TabAlleman I've branched this into a separate question as it seemed fitting... It appears you've just posted a comment too! Thank you :) I agree. I think this should be simplified away from CTE.